# Wordpress Domain Redirects

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, multiple-domains

I recently updated to Wordpress 4.4.1 from I believe 3.5 (it was a very old site that hasn't been updated in a very long time) and since the upgrade, I've been having issues with multiple domains.

I originally had 3 different domains all working off the one wordpress install, serving up different content and styles based on the domain. However, since the upgrade, each domain just redirects to the main domain.

I'm not entirely sure what would of caused this, but any help would greatly be appreciated as I now have 2 sites that are effectively gone.

Thanks!

Comment: It's odd to me that this even worked in the first place.  WordPress stores a "domain" in the database, and when you visit, it automatically loads based on that domain, so even if you had 3 different domains, that would be really weird.  How did you have different domains serving different content? Is this an MU installation?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, yeah honestly I'm not sure how it worked in the first place, like I mentioned, it was built such a long time ago :S

To serve up the different styles and content I was basically just checking which ever domain was being served, then setting a var based on that.

Wasn't a mu site

Comment: Actually, I believe the domain stuff was setup through the hosting provider. Essentially, domain 2 and 3 would just mirror domain 1, but set the variable and serve different content/styles based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution here and it works perfectly!

http://davidmregister.com/dynamic-wp-siteurl/

Essentially, you want to edit your wp-config.php file to contain the following:

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
  define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/* THIS IS CUSTOM CODE CREATED AT ZEROFRACTAL TO MAKE SITE ACCESS DYNAMIC */
$currenthost = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$currentpath = preg_replace('@/+$@','',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
$currentpath = preg_replace('/\/wp.+/','',$currentpath);
define('WP_HOME',$currenthost.$currentpath);
define('WP_SITEURL',$currenthost.$currentpath);
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', $currenthost.$currentpath.'/wp-content');
define('WP_PLUGIN_URL', $currenthost.$currentpath.'/wp-content/plugins');
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $currenthost.$currentpath );
@define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', './');
```

However, I had some issues using this when wordpress was in it's own folder, but worked fine when moved to the root.

Comment: Link in answer is dead.